# Blender 2.91 Smoke Sims and Marmoset Toolbag

Tags: export, smoke-simulation

I'm sure this question has been asked many times before, but is there an easy way to "export" a smoke simulation to be used in Marmoset Toolbag 3? After a lot of googling, I know that you can't just export a smoke sim from Blender as an fbx or whatever, so I thought I would try using the volume to mesh modifier but I don't think you can bake that as an animation, at least not from what I've found. Has anyone found a method to bring simulations from Blender into Marmoset Toolbag 3?

Thanks